# How to create static C++ library with multiple headers, source files...?

Tags: c++, makefile, static-libraries, sdl-2, ld

I'm trying to create a static library that will need many different classes. Each class has its own header and source file. I've read lots of online tutorials about making a static library, but they all use simple examples which don't address my needs for this project. So far I've used `ar -crs 'lib.a' obj1.o obj2.o ...` to create the 'lib.a' file.

According to [this tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/427086/how-to-use-linuxs-ar-command-to-create-static-libraries/), after doing that, I have to copy all the definitions from my previous headers into a single header, called 'lib.h'. This manual approach won't work for me, as I want to automate this process in my makefile.

I have gotten it to work by using a 'lib.h' that includes all of the headers in the same directory, but obviously the goal is to have it work outside of the directory, with just 'lib.a' and 'lib.h'.

Another thing that may make things difficult for me is that I'm using a library (SDL2) which requires an ldflag. It ran fine before, but I want to make sure that it also works when I package it into my own library. I don't want to need the ldflag when implementing my library in the future, but rather have it be pre-packaged.

Comment: You don't need to put all the headers in one header if users are happy with including only the headers they need even if it means including a lot of headers. Many libraries provides a "top" header that only contains `#include` lines of all the other header files that are included with the library. That sounds like a better approach for you.

Comment: 1. The command is correct. 2. I'm not sure why you want to combine all your headers to a single header, but there should be automated tools for that. 3. You'll have to link SDL2 when linking your library. If it was a dynamic library, you could link it just to it, and not to the final application. Look into `pkg-config`, which is the standard way of describing what libraries need what flags (including linker flags) to work.

Comment: There’s no need for a ‘lin.h’ file unless your design calls for it. The C++ standard library is an example; there are lots of headers that are organized functionally, and a single ‘.lib’ file.

Comment: "*According to this tutorial*" You really should ignore everything on that website. It can be accurate, but only by accident.

Answer (score 1):

you should have a header file that the callers of your code #include (like stdio.h). This should contain

- function declarations
- constants
- structs
- typedefs
- macros

this file is not generated from other header files, its just your public interface

Then you compile all the .c files (and non public .h files) into .o files

Then you use ar to create the .a file, then ranlib it

Comment: Understood. So basically the process can not be done automatically using make or other means.

Comment: @badusername you do not need an automatic process, just write the header correctly - that should be the starting point of a library - the public interface, ie what it does for callers

Answer (score 0):

Broadly speaking, when you distribute libraries, you don't do so with a single header. You distribute multiple headers, and for the sake of convenience, one of these headers will include all the rest.

I mean, you *can* distribute a library with a single header. But that usually involves *developing* the library such that all interface declarations (and definitions for templates) are all in the same header.

You can craft an omnibus header from a set of headers just by textually concatenating all of the header files you want to distribute together into a single file. You can even hook this into your makefile if you like.